# String to DateTime conversion as per specified format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to have my end result in date format as per the specified format i.e `YYMMDD` how can i get this from a string given as below

```
   string s="110326";
```

Comment: take a look here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336226/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From string to date:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or the other way around:

```
string s = d.ToString("yyMMdd");
```

Also see this article: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: How about the provider for ParesExtract

Comment: No Overload for 2 parameters you need to provide the culture info

Comment: @Vivekh: sorry, I forgot that `ParseExact` required that parameter. I edited the answer. `InvariantCulture` has the advantage of always giving the same result regardless of the user's regional settings. If you want the result to differ based on the user's region, use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

although id recommend

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dateTime))
{
    // Process
}
else
{
    // Handle Invalid Date
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert `DateTime` to some format, you could do,

```
 string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
```

To convert `string Date` in some format to `DateTime object`, you could do

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyMMdd", null);  //Let str="110719"
```

Comment: I asked string to Datetime conversion