# Datetime conversion in C# - using formats

Tags: c#

I need to convert a `String` to `DateTime` format, for this I just tried like

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it's working fine when I pass the value like `05/30/2012`.

But if I try to pass the value as `5/30/2012` its showing error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

To fix this I tried like

```
DateTime.ParseExact(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateOfBirth), "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it's still not working. Here If I try `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateOfBirth)` for the value `5/30/2012` its showing the same format instead of `05/30/2012`.

How can I fix this, can anyone help me here...

check this link
[string to DateTime conversion in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336226/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You could try `DateTime.Parse` instead of `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: ya thats the simple way, but If I use it, its working in my local system, but after hosting the appln in server, its showing same error, thats what I use `parseExact` here

Comment: I'm not near a compiler right now, but what about "M/d/YYYY" as the format? I think the format specifier MM expects a 0 prepended to months 1-9. I'm presuming if you do 5/30/2012, you'll also want to do 5/5/2012 without a leading 0 in the month.

Comment: Check this link. it is similar to your issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336226/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-c-sharp

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336226/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does that mean that I can't use your website in Germany?

Comment: thanks JasonD, I just put `M/d/yyyy`, its working perfectly, can u kindly post this in answer session pls

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336226/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-c-sharp

Comment: thanks stay_hungry, I'll check it and let u know, thanks again for ur response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `M/d/yyyy` instead of the format specifier you're using. Using only a single `M` matches months with leading zeros as well. This is also true for `d`.

Comment: yup u r right, the first method `M/d/yyyy` working perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try just "d" instead of "MM/dd/yyyy".

So, the statement should be:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The documentation for this is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

**Edit**

Oops, I misread the documentation. It should be "M/d/yyyy".

Comment: thanks for ur response, its not working, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your `DateOfBirth` string is always separated by slashes, you could try something like this:

```
string[] dateParts = DateOfBirth.Split('/');
DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0:00}", dateParts[0]) + "/" + string.Format("{0:00}", dateParts[1]) + "/" + string.Format("{0:0000}", dateParts[2]));
```

I think the issue is the format string can't be recognized since `DateOfBirth` is not a `DateTime` object. Thus, you enforce formatting by reformatting the string yourself

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload which might be of your interest

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth,
                    new[] { "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy" },
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This should help you take care of single as well as two digit month part (since `5` is failing for you as the format is `MM`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have separators in your string (ie `/`), you can just do;

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth,"M/d/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That will parse *either single or double digit days/months*. When you use `MM/dd/yyyy`, you're requiring them both to be double digit numbers, and that's obviously not what you want in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to make it culture-independent..

```
var dateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name).DateTimeFormat;
dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 
    Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, "[M]+", "MM"), "[d]+", "dd");

var newDate = date.HasValue ? date.Value.DateTime.ToString("d", dateTimeFormat) : null;
```

Comment: @Shanish: Also notice I've used `MM` and `dd` and not `M` and `d` as required by your case. You may try that too.